# Python threading stuck after 1 loop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, function

working on some threading with python 3 having two things running at the same time. 
Here is the script i was testing with.

```
from threading import Thread
import time as t
x=1
z=1
var=0
def firstFunction():
    global var
    while x == 1:

        var += 1
        t.sleep(1)
def secondFunction():

    while z == 1:
            print(var)
    t.sleep(1)
add=Thread(target=firstFunction)
see=Thread(target=secondFunction)
add.start()
see.start()
```

For some reason when I run it you exprect it to count up, right?
but it just says

> 1

and doesn't end or say error, but if i try a script that has the script ask if you want to see the var it works fine. Any way i can get this to work without the asking? Here is the code with the asking.

```
from threading import Thread
import time as t
x=1
z=1
var=0
def firstFunction():
    global var
    while x == 1:
        var += 1
        t.sleep(1)
def secondFunction():

    while z == 1:
            see1=input("See var? : ")
            if see1 == "y":
                print(var)
            elif seel == "n":
                print("ok")
            else:
                print("not option")
add=Thread(target=firstFunction)
see=Thread(target=secondFunction)
add.start()
see.start()
```

Comment: The main thread terminates right after you start the other two. `.join()` the two threads!

Comment: How could i use .join() in my piece of code? I can't see where it would go in

Comment: `add.join(); see.join()` as the last line.

Comment: Thanks so much, got a bit scared because it was not working but "git bash" goes weird with while loops in idle it works. Can you write that as an answer so i can close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your code like this, the main thread will reach the end and terminate directly after starting both child threads.

You have to wait until the threads are complete. `.join()` will do that and so you just add these lines to the very end your your programm

```
add.join()
see.join()
```

and the main thread will wait until both threads are finished.

Be aware that unlucky constellations of threads and joins can lead to a deadlock.